# Drush cc gives only two options even when I am in root folder

Tags: drush

I am working with `drupal 8, MAMP version 3.5, and drush version 8.1.3`. I have **installed drush globally** and when I enter `drush st` it gives me complete information and shows that drush is installed but when I run `drush cc`, it gives me only two options

1. cancel
2. drush

whereas, it is suppose to give me many options. I am in a root folder of the site I am working on .i.e. `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysites/mysite`. My OS is OSX on macbook pro, just in case if this is mac specific issue.

Done with this step as well:

sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql /var/mysql

Not sure what else to look into, can you anyone please guide? I am new to drush, terminal and mac

Comment: Is the drupal site running?

Comment: Yupx ! drupal site is running fine :)

Comment: does the directory you are in include an index.php file? (`ls -l` to list files)

Comment: Yupx it does have index.php file in that directory which illustrates that I am in root directory :)

Comment: sorry, just wanted to be sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `drush cr` (container rebuild) rather than `drush cc` (clear cache) 
for drupal 8.

Comment: Got this error:  exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such[error]
file or directory' in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysites/mysite/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php:142

Comment: I have resolved the error mentioned in above comment, now drush cr works but drush cc still gives only two options

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which worked for me on this link : https://www.drupal.org/node/1016268#comment-10466949

And the proposed solution on comment # 31 was:

1. Add this to your .bash_profile `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:$PATH`
2. run this then in terminal `source ~/.bash_profile`

It ended my 3 days search to resolve my issue.